# Attempted to read or write protected memory when capture video using Emgu-CV

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, emgucv

I try to capture video using Emgu-CV but I have an error. My code of the following:

```
Timer My_Time = new Timer();
int FPS = 30;

public Form1()
{
       InitializeComponent();

       //Frame Rate
       My_Timer.Interval = 1000 / FPS;
       My_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(My_Timer_Tick);
       My_Timer.Start();
       _capture = new Capture("test.avi");   
}

private void My_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       imageBox.Image = _capture.QueryFrame();
}
```

The error occurs at

```
_capture = new Capture("test.avi");
```

[image]

Thanks.

Detail 
[image]

Comment: Can you post the exception detail for review?

Comment: @MichaelDiFelice, I added the detail above.

Comment: Sorry should've been more clear, can you add the StackTrace to the question details? It's hard to see, but it looks as though it's failing at CreateFileCapture(string filename).   Does the file exist?   Perhaps that is a known issue within Emgu CV.

Comment: Just found this blog post discussing the issue: http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1523

Seems the bug is in OpenCV 2.2. Maybe try getting the latest from the SVN repo and attempting again?

Comment: unless you have to. Use the most recent version of OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

You should not start your timer before the instantiation of your Capture object.
It might be querying frames before your avi video is loaded.

Try just swapping this lines:

```
_capture = new Capture("test.avi");
My_Timer.Start();
```